# Does cast iron hub direction denote flow direction?

Tags: plumbing, drain, cast-iron

I placed a piece of 2x4 over a part of the exposed pipe and used a level (direction flowing left to right), but was wondering: Does the Cast Iron hub placement denote flow directionality as well?

[image]

Comment: Even if it s supposed to denote flow directionality, would you necessarily trust that the guy who installed it did so correctly?